# Has the increased ability of Chinese citizens to travel led to an increased demand for political reform?

Tags: china, demographics, public-opinion, social-class

According to this [article](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/comment/rise-of-the-chinese-tourist/), which presents data from the China Outbound Tourism Research Institute & the United Nations World Tourism Organisation, annual Chinese overseas visits have increased by 1,326% since the turn of the millennium. This would appear to be due at least in part to the large increase in the Chinese middle class in particular, which a [McKinsey study](https://www.mckinsey.com/industries/retail/our-insights/mapping-chinas-middle-class) predicts will rise to 75% of the population in 2022, from just 4% in 2000.

This middle class [has the ability](http://www.shanghaijungle.com/meetthechinesetourist.html) to travel and study around the world - [this World Economic Forum article](https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2019/06/chinese-tourists-spent-250-billion-in-2017/) also attributes the rise in Chinese tourism to relaxed travel restrictions by the Chinese authorities. In particular, many Chinese students choose to study in liberal democracies such as the US and the UK.

Given the explosion in the population of this well-travelled middle class, has this led to an increase in demand for political reform? If so, how has this manifested? If not, how can this incongruence be explained objectively?

Comment: In fact, every answer here would be opinion-based. Maybe even reinforced with appropriate polls. But that would not deny its opinion-basement. Of course, we can enough long speculate about what is logical, and what is not - but would there be an answer? Definitely no

Comment: While I appreciate the comments, I believe an objective answer is possible with the use of polling data. Other questions here are often answered using polls despite the possible underlying biases of the polling organizations.

Comment: There are not enough data to answer this question. I reckon that the statistics say that the middle class is growing, but that happens within China where the local cost of life is lower than in developed countries (look for the differences between China GDP nominal and at PPP). So do all those people in the middle class really have the spending power to travel and study abroad? I doubt that, I think they represent more an elite than a significant group of the population. Furthermore it would be the elite which is benefiting from the current situation.

Comment: Comments cleaned up. Please don't use comments to answer the question, to debate its subject matter and especially not to debate completely unrelated subject matters (like the 2016 US presidential election or whether or not we live in a "post truth society"). For more information on how comments on questions should and should not be used, please review [the help article about the commenting privilege](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).